# jQuery: How to get a set of elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a simle `html` `div` with a variable number of input checkboxes and i whould like to chek which chekbox is cheked and which isn't

HTML code:

```
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" val="1"/>Check One<br/>
    <input type="checkbox" val="2" checked="checked"/>Check Two<br/>
</div>
```

Javascript code:

```
var $kids = $("div").children("input");

for (var i = 0; i < $kids.length; i ++) {
    // if i alert($kids[i]); i get [object HTMLInputElement] how can i work with it?
    alert ($kids[i].val()); // doesn't work
}
```

In [jQuery site](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/children) i read `children()` method can "Get a set of elements containing all of the unique immediate children of each of the matched set of elements." but what is a "set of elements"and how can I work with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**:

I should have read your question more carefully you were asking how to iterate over the the set. as has already been stated you can do:

```
$('div input:checked').each(function(){
   // do something with the item this is always the current element in the iteration
});
```

or

```
$.each(yourVar, function(i, e){
   // your var can be anything iterable really... an object, an array i is the index and e is the value for that index
});
```

---

`$('div input:checked');` should work.

Answer (score 3):

`$("input:checkbox:checked")` or `$("input:checkbox:not(:checked)")`

You should add an id to your container to limit the options...
`<div id="container"> inputs here </div>`

Then you can use...
`var checked = $("#container input:checkbox:checked");

var unchecked = $("#container input:checkbox:not(:checked)");`

Answer (score 0):

Working with a set of elements is very similar to working with a single element in jQuery.. There are a lot of methods you can use to split the segments up `.each()` allows you to work with each matched element, `.css()`, `.animate()`, `.show()` etc all work with all the elements matched in the set as well.  You can used `.get()` or just an array index `[0]` to get single elements out of the jQuery matched set.

Answer (score 0):

- This selector will get you all the checkboxes: `input:checkbox`
- This selector will get you all the checkboxes that are checked: `input:checkbox:checked`
- This selector will get you all the checkboxes that are **not** checked: `input:checkbox:not(:checked)`

Answer (score 0):

You can access the elements with $kids[i], but what you're getting back isn't a JQuery object, it's a standard DOM element. Therefore you can't call the .val() method, because that doesn't exist for DOM objects.

So really you only have to make a small modification:

```
var $kids = $("div").children("input");

for (var i = 0; i < $kids.length; i ++) {
    // if i alert($kids[i]); i get [object HTMLInputElement] how can i work with it?
    alert ($kids[i].checked); // does work :-)
}
```

Hope this helps!